Has Windows a C API for Linked List in user space?
I found LIST_ENTRY.
The page states Kernel-Mode Driver Reference. And clearly, I did not manage to use it in  user space as expected.
Here is my test:
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    LIST_ENTRY message_list;

    InitializeListHead(&message_list);

    if (!IsListEmpty(&message_list)) {
        puts("Not expected");
        return -1;
    }

    puts("Hello World");
    return 0;
}

With my CMake:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)
project (CMakeHelloWorld)

add_executable (CMakeHelloWorld main.c)
target_link_libraries(CMakeHelloWorld ntdll kernel32)

The build error is:
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol InitializeListHead referenced in function main [C:\test\build\CMakeHelloWorl
d.vcxproj]
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol IsListEmpty referenced in function main [C:\test\build\CMakeHelloWorld.vcxpr 
oj]
C:\test\build\Debug\CMakeHelloWorld.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals [C:\test\build\CMakeHelloWorld.vcxproj]

Obviously I could create my own LinkedList API but I find it weird Windows does not have it.

There's no generic linked list in the POSIX API either, at least to my knowledge.  Why would you expect Windows to provide this?

The C language does not have a a built-in dynamic list data structure such as some higher-level languages (e.g. Python, Javascript) do, nor a standard data structure library in the way that some higher-level languages (C++, Java, ...) do.  It is possible that there is a Windows-specific API, but inasmuch as Microsoft much prefers C++ over C, I'm inclined to think that they would suggest C++ and std::vector or similar.

Linux has a C API: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/queue.7.html
I also found suggestion of the C++ std::vector but I am looking for a C API.

You could copy sys/queue.h from somewhere. It's all done with macros, and no external functions.

@IanAbbott obviously copying sys/queue.h could be an option. But the initial question was to know if there was an "official" API.
Note for people who would decide to copy sys/queue.h, be aware of the code license.

The main reason why it doesn't exist might be because linked lists are almost never the correct solution to any problem. This statement is false in general: "shifting static arrays is slow, adding an item to a linked list is fast". The truth is that linked lists are slower in pretty much every scenario. On top of that they add extra complexity. This is one of them stupid things taught in school since the 1980s and nobody questions it because they too were taught to use them in school.

The user-mode sdk has an InitializeListHead in Msputils.h, note that it is a define, not actually a function despite the docs calling it one.

Msputils.h is a C++ header and is not supporting C language. I have just tried with my above sample.

@OlivierM The macros could be copied from the C++ msputils.h header to a separate C header.

@IanAbbott See my above comment saying that copying the macros could be an option. But the initial question was to know if there was an "official" API. It looks like there is none so far.
